# How to use output variable for replacing variables in config file

Tags: octopus-deploy

I have defined 3 steps in my deploy process:

1. Generate password (Run a Script)
2. Deploy admin API (Deploy an IIS Web Site)
3. Deploy public API (Deploy an IIS Web Site)

In step 1, I use following PowerShell script to generate random password:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web")

$pwd = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(15,2)

Set-OctopusVariable -name "Password" -value $pwd -sensitive
```

There are some variables defined in the project under `Variables` section, and they correctly replace corresponding values in config files in step 2 and 3.

My question is, how to use `Password` variable from step 1 to replace corresponding fields in config files in steps 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the name of the step that the variable was created in when you retrieve it:

In the config file (in the package for steps 2 and 3) use a value like this:

#{Octopus.Action[NameOfStep1].Output.Password}

Comment: This approach didn't work. Instead, I had to create variable which uses this syntax in my project page, and to use `Replace appSettings and connectionString entries in any .config files` feature for required steps..